# Can I specify the random seed for Bogus?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bogus

I'm using [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) to generate test data.

Is there a way to set the seed it uses so it generates the same test data, in the same order?

For example, this test would fail:

```
var person1 = new Bogus.Person();
var person2 = new Bogus.Person();
Assert.AreEqual(person1.FullName, person2.FullName);
```

However, is there a way to reset the seed so that it wouldn't, ie:

```
Bogus.Config.SetSeed(1);
var person1 = new Bogus.Person();

Bogus.Config.SetSeed(1);
var person2 = new Bogus.Person();

Assert.AreEqual(person1.FullName, person2.FullName);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [readme](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) has an example of this:

```
//Set the randomzier seed if you wish to generate repeatable data sets.
Randomizer.Seed = new Random(8675309);
```

However, setting the seed means that the results of the random generator are *consistent*. To do what you want, you'll need to reset the seed before each call to get the same results.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I saw it somewhere.  I do only need it done once per test run, but I wrote the example to indicate I wanted control of it, just to make sure i didn't get an answer that required restarting the app domain.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer will change the global seed, which isn't really nice:

- There is a change you can't run tests in parallel
- There is a change that test code is dependent of each other

The recommend way is to change the seed of the Faker itself:

For the non-generic `Faker`:

```cs
var seed = 8675309;
var faker = new Faker()
faker.Random = new Randomizer(seed );
```

The generic `Faker` has a helper, `UseSeed`:

```cs
var seed = 8675309;
var faker = new Faker<MyClass>().UseSeed(seed);
```